# Socket.io is increasing cost on Google cloud run

Tags: reactjs, node.js, websocket, socket.io, google-cloud-run

I have implemented Socket.io for chat feature on my React application and I have used node js for backend which is deployed on Google Cloud. Since I have deployed chat it increasing Google Cloud cost.
I think this is because of regular ping pong method that Socket uses to keep connection between server and client. What can I do for reducing Google cloud cost?

I have researched on how to stop ping pong method when user is not interacting with chat but I did not found anything.
I want that ping pong method should stop immediately when user exist from chat.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.